# RequestId and instanceId Bing Speech Recognition

Tags: api, speech-to-text, bing

I am trying to use the bing speech to text api and I have everything set up except for the requestid and instanceid. The api tells me WHAT they are but doesnt tell me HOW to get them can anyone help me out here? this is very frustrating and I cant figure out what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had an error:

> WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Unable to get
>   requestid from the query string..

I did not understand where to get the requestid, so I took the one in the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedrest) and it works:

```
string url = "https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&requestid=39530efe-5677-416a-98b0-93e13ec93c2b";
```